# How to continue on with a LINQ query

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have a linq query:

```
var list = (from x in db.students
                        where x.name== student_name 
                        select new
                        {
                            x.date,
                            x.Student_id
                        }
```

I don't want to execute `.toList()` query just yet, I want to Select more properties of a student at a later stage, for example:

```
x.student_age 
x.student_name
```

At a later stage.

For example, adding on to the var list:

```
    var list = (from x in db.students
                        where x.name== student_name 
                        select new
                        {
                            x.date,
                            x.Student_id
                            x.student_age 
                            x.student_name
                        }.toList();
```

How should I go about doing this??

Comment: Unable to understand your question. Please re-phrase it for more understandability.

Comment: You should define **want to Select more at a later stage** more.

Comment: `.toList()` will show all fields. Are you want select field you want?

Comment: more what? more properties of a student or more students?

Comment: @Marco more properties of a student

Comment: @P.Pat hi, I want to Select more properties of a student at a later stage. How am I able to add more Select Properties ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are approaching the problem the wrong way. If you do not know, which properties of an object you want to select, why do you select a subset at all?

```
var list = (from x in db.students
            where x.name== student_name 
            select x);
```

At this point an time, you have not yet materialized your query. It is still an `IQueryable<T>`.
Now when you know, which properties you need, you can still do a select into an anonymous object, or preferrably a ViewModel-class:

```
list = list.Select(x => new StudentViewModel {
    Id = x.Id,
    Name = x.Name,
    /* ....*/
});
```

If you want to go with an anonymous object, it is simply:

```
list = list.Select(x => new {
    Id = x.Id,
    Name = x.Name,
    /* ....*/
});
```

Now, when you call `list.ToList()` it is materialized and the query is executed. Your `IQueryable<T>` becomes an `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: Beautiful, I will test this out, thank you so much !

Comment: Don't forget to declare your ViewModel class or you will run into yet another compile time error ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do select query at later stage if your query is still deferred query.

```
var list = from x in db.students
           where x.name == student_name
```

then in the next stage:

```
var list1 = from x in list
            select new
            {
                x.date,
                x.student_id
                x.student_age 
                x.student_name
            }
```

Comment: That will not compile. The query syntax requires you to have a select statement.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, you can add select x on the first query.